# Why do I have to constantly restart my R session for correct RAM usage?

Tags: sql, r, odbc, ram

Good afternoon,

I usually work with millions of observations loaded from an Oracle DB using ODBC. I was commonly using Stata for the loading and wrangling but I want to start using R for more freedom.

The problem I encounter is that while Stata uses 700 MB of RAm to load a dataset R uses 4 GB. According to people, the problem could be R's natural data types. Nevertheless, once I decide to remove the dataset from the enviroment of R I still get some 1 GB RAM usage even without the data loaded (and after I run `gc()`. I have to constantly restart R session to get a good RAM usage. Is this a known problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `R` uses a lot of memory. See the help page `?gc`, especially the `Details` section: "it can be useful to call `gc` after a large object has been removed, as this may prompt R to return memory to the operating system."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that I also run gc() after I rm() the object but the memory is still allocated to the Rsession.exe process which is problematic

Comment: install `gdata` package. Then run `ll` to see the memory usages.